# Cannot reference an object created in main from outside main

Tags: java, object, reference, program-entry-point

I have a class with a list of persons. I have made a class PersonBeholder (which means PersonContainer in norwegian). I also have a class Person, and a main class that makes the relations between the persons. I am having problems when i try to reference the general list of persons from outside the main class.

```
class TestPersoner{
public static void main (String [ ] args){

   **PersonBeholder pl = new PersonBeholder();**

    Person Emil = new Person("Emil");
    Person Nils = new Person("Nils");

    pl.settInnPerson(Emil);        //this populates the list
    pl.settInnPerson(Nils);

    }

}
```

Now i have problems when i try to reference the PersonBeholder pl from outside main:

```
public void blirVennMed(Person p){
if(!pl.erIbeholder(p.hentNavn())) System.out.print("This is not going to work");
//this does check if there is someone in the container named p.hentNavn()
}
```

## OUTPUT

```
TestPersoner.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
if(!pl.erIbeholder(p.hentNavn())) System.out.print("This is not going to work");
    ^
  symbol:   variable pl
  location: class Person
1 error
```

Now I did it like this:

```
class TestPersoner{
public static PersonBeholder pl = new PersonBeholder();
public static void main (String [ ] args){  

    Person Emil = new Person("Emil");
    Person Nils = new Person("Nils");

    pl.settInnPerson(Emil);        //this populates the list
    pl.settInnPerson(Nils);

    }

}
```

And it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are not using one of the pre-existing Java collections (like [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Local variables` are only confined to the method scope. you can't use them outside the method that you defined them in.they simply get GC'D after the method completes unless you return them explicitly.

Comment: Is there a way to make it global?

Comment: yepp, declare the object you want as an instance variable. essentially make it private and provide getter/setter for it so that other objects can access it through them .

Answer (score 1):

The scope of your object is in the main-method. If you want to use it outside of it, declare it as a member of class TestPersoner or pass it to a method as an argument.

Comment: How do I declare it as a member of TestPersoner? EDIT: nevermind, I did it!

Comment: You should consider the basics of Java. It seems, that you don't know much about how to structure classes and access members. Look at [this](https://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~slonnegr/oosd/JavaBasics.pdf).